# How to change the color of the currently selected line in a code assist popup in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, colors, popup, line, highlight

I've recently downloaded Eclipse 3.6, everything works fine, but there is one issue that really frustrates me. The highlight color of a currently selected item in a code assist popup is barely visible against white background. I've tried to mess with color settings, but it seems that there is no option for my needs. The line highlight color set in Windows color scheme is only used to highlight in a focused popup.

Answer (score 26):

I believe it is hidden in another part of Preferences. I personally wanted to change the highlighted or currently selected line color, and could not find anything in Colors and Fonts. Ends up it was in...

General -> Editors -> Text Editors

And you just need to go through every option in the "Appearance color options" box there. One is "Current line highlight" and that fixed my problem. I hope it helps yours!

Answer (score 1):

I know you're trying to change the highlight color, but if the problem is contrast you can change the content assist background color, and get this kind of contrast

[image: content assist example]

The setting is General->Appearance->Color Basic->Content Assist Background[image: preference setting]

Then it's just a matter of finding colors that please you.

Comment: As far as I remember this setting was not present in the previous versions of Eclipse. I am now using IDEA, which does not have this kind of problems

Comment: You asked about Eclipse 3.6 (Helios). This feature **certainly was** in Helios and it was also in the prior 3.5 (Galileo) version as well.

Comment: That changes the colour for the un-selected items in the list.  The question is how to change the colour of the currently selected item in the list.

Comment: Did I not make that obvious with my opening statement? And the body of the question made it seem likely that the OP really wanted better visibility of the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences->General->Appearance->Color and Fonts then find the appropriate category.

Some editors will have support for "Colored labels - match highlight"

Comment: Did you read my message? I've said that there is no option for setting it. It seems that eclipse derives some colors from windows color theme screws everything up in the process

Comment: Ah, sorry. There are lots of "color settings" in Eclipse, but sometimes users don't find the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I've found a solution for windows XP. If you go to `Control Panel` -> `Display` -> `Appearance` -> `Advanced` and select `3D Objects` under `Item` you can change the color of this highlight to a darker color.

However it does change the appearance of other parts of your windows.