# Eclipse Juno: How to change tab color?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, tabs, ubuntu-12.04

Unfortunately the latest update of Eclipse plugins discarded Inigo and installed Juno. It took me a lot of time to make it look like the previous version, but I cannot get it managed to change the blue tab color. Any ideas which setting or css this is?

[image]

[UPDATE]
There are settings to change the colors, but these settings don't cause any effect, so can I assumed it is a bug?

[image]

Comment: In Package Explorer, if there are many Java files, one of that is open in the editor , then in Package Explorer, it is highlighted by defaly with gray color. is there way to highlight it with differenct color. ?  I am already using  " Link with Editor" option

Comment: @javafan Maybe you can manipulate it in the OS itself. I made this like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628864/how-to-modify-color-of-inactive-line-in-code-assist-in-eclipse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible with the default themes and Eclipse installation, but there are workarounds:

**Easy, but restricted:** You can install the [Eclipse 4 Chrome Theme](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/), where you can configure each color, the space between parts and much more: [image]

**Complicated, but "anything goes":** Install the E4 CSS editor from the E4 [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.12). Modify the CSS as described in [Switching tab styles](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS#Switching_tab_styles).

Comment: Thanks, but I hate this design of the tabs you get with this theme. It's almost as ugly as the GTK theme. I need to change the color of the classic design.

Comment: Updated to give you an alternative to change that color.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your instructions, but when I change the CSS it changes only the colors of the tabs which are NOT currently selected although the attribute is called swt-selected-tabs-background. So it's exactly the opposite of what it should do. So either I need another attribute for this or this Eclipse is totally buggy.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that .MPartStack.active class. It works now, thanks :)