# How to change a background of currently active tab in tab list in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3) with dark theme and everything is fine and dandy except for one annoying thing. In text editor, tab that shows opened file name is highlighted with bright color which makes it difficult to see the name. I have to hover to read it. I've been looking at preferences and couldn't find where it can be modified, there must be a way. Picture is attached, the area in question is the background color of ZoneManager tab.
[image]

**UPDATE** people pointed out the answer to the same question in different wording. I plan not to remove the question so people could find an answer if they use different wording. 
**ANSWER--->**  [Cannot change color of Eclipse editor tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22841415/2985643)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot change color of Eclipse editor tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22841415/2985643) and [Eclipse Juno: How to change tab color?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11961098/2985643)

Comment: @skomisa I don't know how you found it, but yes you are correct it is the same question. thank you for pointing it out. Just in case people like me that used different wording end up here I'll post the link to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to 
`window -> preferences -> general -> appearance -> Colors and Fonts` 
You'll see a text entry area 
type `focus` 
 and you will see parameters that need to changed for your needs.
[image]